# Backbone.js and Django (Without Tastypie)

Tags: django, backbone.js

I'm using Django for my site and trying to incorporate backbone.js. Backbone encourages using Tastypie - but I would rather not. Is there a way to use backbone.js and django without tastypie? Are there any examples out there of how to do this?

Comment: You might also want to check out http://django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been were you are. Needed to just make a custom API for backbone to read for the specific instances.

All that really means, is making custom views in your views.py and attaching them to custom urls in urls.py for backbone. Your views will have to return a JSON version of the object or objects

So you end up with friendly looking urls that backbone likes

For example if I had a model of boxes and I want to write a url and a view that sends all the boxes in my database to my frontend delivering them to backbone - I could make a url like this   /api/v1/box/all/         really anything you want. In your view you just need to remember to return JSON.

Remember - you need update views to to update from backbone syncings (tastypie PUTS)
something like  /api/v1/box/3/update?updatedinfodata

Let me know if you would like me to expand or show some code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to bot use TastyPie and just build your own API.

You just need to know Backbone sends to the API and data it expects to receive.